# How to Send Request to Microsoft Dynamics Navision2016 from asp.net Application by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I am Working with Civil & Real Estate Domain ERP Application. Now i want integrate our App with Microsoft Dynamics Navision. we  bought that Nav Product and hosted in our server. Now I want to know how to send request and receive response from NAV Server by using C#  Language.such as creating a groups and Ledgers(For Finance Module) and Checking GL Exisiting or Not. and Particular Company is Existing and Sending Payment Data to Server through we Request etc..,
**Mainly I want to Know how to Communicate with NAV Server Using Web Requests.**
any body Please Help Me....

Comment: Is there documentation? The question is off topic if you don't show your own research and ask about a specific problem with the code you have tried.

Comment: No sir, there is no documents. now only we are going to integrate our ERP app with NAV

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with dynamics nav via web-requests.
In order to use them, you need to enable them in the "web requests" page. if you have specific needs like getting the gl entries etc. you need to publish pages / codeunits in order to do so.
authorisation is done via http header. protocol can be soap starting with version navision 2009 SP1 or ODATA (basicly a rest api) i think from NAV 2015 on